# rviz screen problem

Tags: ros, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

I'm working with rviz and when I  run `rosrun rviz rviz` I get the screen like [this](https://youtu.be/kgltgNDIpxs). I searched a lot and I tried several solutions but none helped.

I'm using NVIDIA C61 [GeForce 7025 / nForce 630a] graphics card with nvidia-304 driver installed. I also use ubuntu 14.04 and ROS indigo 1.11.20.

any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240724/rviz-screen-problem/) by [Ghazal](https://answers.ros.org/users/27477/ghazal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like a default RViz screen to me...are you sure there's a problem?

You might need to set a [robot state publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher) or other information sources, then select and/or set up appropriate displays/panels...

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2016-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ghazal](https://answers.ros.org/users/27477/ghazal/) on 2016-07-30**:
thank you for your reply.

if you take a look at these photos you will get what my problem is. guess the previous video was not in a good quality!

[link text](https://i.imgsafe.org/cf8337856c.jpg)
[link text](https://i.imgsafe.org/cf8dfb0c26.jpg)

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2016-07-31**:
I can't make out the contents of those images. The resolution is fine (about 1080 x X), but it looks like the scan lines are interleaved. Can you just do a screen capture rather than taking a picture of the screen? (Try the 'screenshot' program.)

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-07-31**:
"you will get what my problem is" or... you just explain it yourself.

**Comment by [Ghazal](https://answers.ros.org/users/27477/ghazal/) on 2016-07-31**:
I didn't know how to explain my problem that's why I used photos. the problem is exactly what you said! when I run rviz it looks like the scan lines are interleaved and the colors are mixed some how. at first I tried the screenshot program but the output is just a black screen that can't be opened.

**Comment by [Ghazal](https://answers.ros.org/users/27477/ghazal/) on 2016-07-31**:
and the point is that all my screen becomes like this not only the rviz window and I have to restart my pc to get the screen back and be able to use it again.

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2016-08-01**:
Ah. That seems like less of a ROS problem and more of a graphics card issue. But I don't know and it's out of my general knowledge area. Sorry, hope someone else can help...

**Comment by [Ghazal](https://answers.ros.org/users/27477/ghazal/) on 2016-08-01**:
yeah I think the problem is with my graphics card as well but I only have this problem with rviz. by the way, thank you :)